# Web Grid displays all data when you click the header link while in category, how do you make it stay in the current category list?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a web grid (MVC Razor) with Category buttons and even a category drop-down that basically does the same. When I press the category button, the web grid populates the category list, just like it should, but when I go to sort the category, it displays all the data list from then on (everything) and the category list is gone to the everything list. How do you make it stay in the category list when clicking the header link to sort only the category list that is current???

```
  [Code] 
     //Razor Page: 

      @model YardDog.Model.YardDogModel
@{
Layout = null;
ViewBag.Title = "Yard Dog";
string LblUserName = (string)Session["LblUserName"];
ViewBag.UserLocation = Session["UserLocation"];
ViewBag.UserName = Session["UserName"];
string LblUserLocationNumber = (string)Session["LblUserLocationNumber"];
Model.LblUserLocationNumber = (string)Session["LblUserLocationNumber"];
string LblPlantLocation = Model.PlantLocation.ToString();
Model.UserPlantLocation = (string)Session["LblPlantLocation"];
bool AlreadyInTable = Model.AlreadyInTable;
Model.ErrorFoundWebGridUser = (string)Session["Duplicates Found"];

    WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model.LocationDatas, canPage: true, canSort: 
true, sortDirectionFieldName: "Location, Section", rowsPerPage: 50);
    webGrid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

//Extract the TempData to the Label to show UserName.
var UserName = Session["LblUserName"];
var Title = Session["UserTitle"];
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title>Yard Dog</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/YardDogStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
/>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 />

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/YardDogStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
@{ 
    if (LblUserName == null)
    {

        Response.Redirect("../LogIn/UserLogin");
    }
}



<!-- Redirect to Admin Page if detected Admin exists -->
@if (ViewBag.UserLocation == "Minneapolis")
{
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/YardDogAdmin");
}
<div id="time"></div>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();

        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s; //Get the 
     time.
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Date: " + today; //Get the Date.
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    startTime();
</SCRIPT>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ScrollableGridPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=webGrid.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 300
        });
        $('#<%=webGrid.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 300
        });
    });
</script>
<script>


    $('#accordion').on('click', function () {
        $('#OpenPanelButton').next().slideToggle(400);
        $('#ClosePanelButton').next().siblings('.accordion').slideUp(400);
    });

    $('#OpenPanelButton').hide();
    $('#ClosePanelButton').hide();

</script>
<script src="Scripts/ScrollableGridPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ScrollableGridPlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=webGrid.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 300,
            Width: 467
        });
    });

    </script>
    <div>
    <form id="formYardDog" class="formYardDog" runat="server" method="post">
        <div>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                
            <h2 style="color:red">Yard Dog Testing</h2><br />
        </div>
        <!-- Call the Controller Action method to Log-Out. -->
        <input type="button" value="LogOut" 
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("LogOut", "Home/")'" id="LogOut"/>
       
        <!--Refresh form every 12 seconds-->
        <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="12;" />-->
        <hr />

        <div class="DivDropDown">

            @{ int firstRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + 1;
                int lastRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + 
            webGrid.Rows.Count();
            }
            <div id="RowCountTop"><b>Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of 
           @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div>

            <br />
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = 
           "formYardDog" }))
            {
                <label>Welcome: @LblUserName</label> <label>User Location: 
          @LblUserLocationNumber</label><br />

                <label style="color:red" id="SelectPlantLocationLbl">Please select a 
          Plant Location:</label><br />
                <label style="color:red" 
          id="ErrorFoundWebGridUser">@Model.ErrorFoundWebGridUser</label>
                @Html.Hidden(Model.AlreadyInTable.ToString(), new { @id = 
          "AlreadyInTable" })

                //Loop to Get Dictionary List Buttons with Distinct 
               Section Values.
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Section.Count; i++)
                {

                    //If the SectionCity is not null, then back- 
                     ground color to red.
                    if (@Model.Section[i].Value == SectionCity)
                    {

                        <button name="@Html.NameFor(model => 
        model.Section)" value=@Model.Section[i].Value 
        id="ddlSectionButtonsSelected" runat="server" , new { 
      class="ddlSectionButtonsSelected" onClick="focusMe(this);" 
        style="background-color:red; color:white" 
        }>@Model.Section[i].Value</button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // var Count = i;
                        <!--  <input type="submit" 
         name="Html.NameFor(model => model.Section)" 
       value=Model.Section[i].Value id="ddlSectionButtons" , new { 
       class="ddlSectionButtons" onClick="focusMe(this);" }/> -->
                        <button name="@Html.NameFor(model => 
       model.Section)" value=@Model.Section[i].Value 
       id="ddlSectionButtons" runat="server" , new { 
        class="ddlSectionButtons" 
       onClick="focusMe(this);"}>@Model.Section[i].Value</button>
                    }

                }
                //Modify if the User is designated 101 UserLocation show the 
           PlantLocation Drop-Down Box.
                //var userLocation = "(ViewBag.UserLocation)";
                if (LblUserLocationNumber == "101" && LblUserLocationNumber != "")
                {
                    // Response.Redirect("/Admin/YardDogAdmin");
                    <button text="All" value=" " type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model 
        => model.Section)" , new { onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" 
         onClick="focusMe(this);" id="ddlSectionAllButton" class="ddlSectionButtons" 
          placeholder="All" hidden="hidden" })>All</button>
                    <br /><br />

                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlantLocation, 
       Model.PlantLocation, "PlantLocation", new { onchange = 
         "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlWarehouses101", @class = 
     "ddlWarehouses101" })
                }

                <!-- All Sections Button for PlantLocation -->
                if (LblUserLocationNumber != "101" && LblUserLocationNumber != "")
                {
                    <button text="All" value=" " type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model 
       => model.Section)" , new { onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" 
       onClick="focusMe(this);" id="ddlSectionAllButton" class="ddlSectionButtons" 
       placeholder="All" hidden="hidden" })>All</button>
                }
                //Testing button selection (Below):
                //@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Section, new { Class = "name", 
       placeholder="All", type="submit", value=" " })

            }

            <!---  <button class="YardDogAdminButton" 
   onclick="location.href='/YardDogAdmin/YardDogAdmin'" type="button" 
     target="_blank">Admin Page</button> -->
            <br />

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Section, Model.Section, "Section", new 
      { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlSection", @class = 
       "ddlSection" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlantLocation, Model.PlantLocation, 
        "PlantLocation", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = 
         "ddlWarehouses", @class = "ddlWarehouses" })
            <br />

            <hr />
           
            <div id="content">
                @webGrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
       headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
       footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
       //alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
       selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
       rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
       mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
       htmlAttributes: new { @id = "webGrid" },
       columns: webGrid.Columns(
       webGrid.Column(header: "Actions", format:@<span class="link">
            <!--Add Checkbox here-->
            <!-- Note: We can add clickable rows as an option for user using a checkbox, 
          one selects the data move and the other move to selection. -->

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SelectedMoveIsChecked, new { @Class = 
         "SelectedMoveIsChecked", @id = "SelectedMoveIsChecked", @checked = false })
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SelectedMoveToChecked, new { @Class = 
        "SelectedMoveToChecked", @id = "SelectedMoveToChecked", @checked = false })


            <!-- Don't allow the User to pick on the Edit and Clear Links unless they 
       pick the PlantLocation dropdown first.' -->
            @if (Model.UserPlantLocation == null)
         {
        <a class="Edit" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Edit</a>
        <a class="Clear" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Clear</a>
        <a class="Update" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Update</a>
        <a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Cancel</a>
 }
            @if (Model.UserPlantLocation != null)
         {
        <a class="Edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
        <a class="Clear" href="javascript:;">Clear</a>
        <a class="Update" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Update</a>
        <a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Cancel</a>
 }
        </span>),

       webGrid.Column(columnName: "Location", header: "Location", format: @<div>
            <label id="LocationLbl" class="label">@item.Location</label><br />



            <!--  <input id="Location" class="text" type="text" value="@item.Location" 
       style="display:none" /><br /> -->
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationAppended, 
       Model.LocationAppended, "Section/Location", new { IReadOnlyDictionary = 
        "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "RowLocationDropDownList", @class = 
      "RowLocationDropDownList", @visibility = "hidden", @placeholder = "Location" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DuplicateAppended, 
        Model.DuplicateAppended, "Section/Location", new { IReadOnlyDictionary = 
       "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "RowLocationDupDropDownList", @class = 
      "RowLocationDupDropDownList", @visibility = "hidden", @placeholder = "Location" })

        </div>, style: "Location", canSort: true),

       webGrid.Column(columnName: "Section", header: "Section", format: @<div>
            <label id="SectionLbl" class="label">@item.Section</label>
            <!-- <input id="Section" class="text" type="text" value="@item.Section" 
       style="display:none" /> -->

        </div>, style: "Section", canSort: true),

        webGrid.Column(columnName: "TrailerNumber", header: "TrailerNumber", format: 
      @<div>
            <label id="TrailerNumberLbl" class="label">@item.TrailerNumber</label>
            <input id="TrailerNumber" class="text" type="text" 
       value="@item.TrailerNumber" style="display:none" /><br />
            <!--- Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TrailerNumberAppended, 
        Model.TrailerNumberAppended, "Trailer Number", new {id="DropDownTrailerNumber", 
        class="text", visability="hidden"}) -->
        </div>, style: "TrailerNumber", canSort: true),

        webGrid.Column(columnName: "CarrierName", header: "CarrierName", format: @<div>
            <label id="CarrierNameLbl" class="label">@item.CarrierName</label>
            <input id="CarrierName" class="text" type="text" value="@item.CarrierName" 
        style="display:none" /><br />
            @Html.DropDownList("Carrier", Model.CarrierNameAppended, "Carrier List", new 
       { @id = "DropDownListCarrier", @class = "text", @hidden = "hidden" })
        </div>, style: "CarrierName", canSort: true),

       webGrid.Column(columnName: "Status", header: "Status", format: @<div>
            <label id="LoadCommodityStatusLbl" 
       class="label">@item.LoadCommodityStatus</label>
            <input id="LoadCommodityStatus" class="text" type="text" 
        value="@item.LoadCommodityStatus" style="display:none" /><br />
            @Html.DropDownList("Status", Model.StatusAppended, "Status List", new { @id 
       = "DropDownListStatus", @class = "text", @hidden = "hidden" })
        </div>, style: "LoadCommodityStatus", canSort: true),

      webGrid.Column(columnName: "StatusDate", header: "StatusDate", format: @<div>
            <label id="DateLoadedLbl" class="label">@item.DateLoaded</label>
            <!-- <input id="DateLoaded" class="text" type="text" 
      value="@item.DateLoaded" style="display:none" /> -->
        </div>, style: "DateLoaded", canSort: true),

      webGrid.Column(columnName: "UserName", header: "UserName", format: @<div>
            <label id="UserNameLbl" class="label">@item.UserName</label>
            <!--  <input id="UserName" class="text" type="text" value="@item.UserName" 
       style="display:none" /> -->
        </div>, style: "UserName", canSort: true),

        webGrid.Column(header: "PlantLocation", format: @<div>
            <label id="PlantLocationLbl" class="label">@item.PlantLocation</label>
            <!--  <input id="PlantLocation" class="text" type="text" 
         value="@item.PlantLocation" style="display:none" /> -->
        </div>, style: "PlantLocation"),

         webGrid.Column(header: "RowPageID", format: @<div>
            <label id="LocationIDLbl" class="label">@item.LocationID</label>
        </div>, style: "LocationID"))),

                <div id="RowCountBpttom"><b>Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of 
      @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="WebGridTable">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/YardDog.js"></script>

 </body>

  //Controller:

             //Population Controller. 
    public YardDogModel PopulateModel(string country, string city)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3 entities = new PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3())
        {
            YardDogModel model = new YardDogModel()
            {
                LocationDatas = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                // group c.Section by c.PlantLocation into g
                                 where c.PlantLocation == country && c.Section == city && c.Section == c.Section && c.Location == c.Location && c.PlantLocation == country || string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) && c.PlantLocation == country
                                 select c).ToList(),

                LocationList = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Location) && c.Location != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) //&& city == c.Section //&& country == c.PlantLocation //  && country == c.PlantLocation// && townList == c.Location // && city == c.Section && country == c.PlantLocation
                                select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Location, Value = c.Location }).Distinct().ToList(),

                SectionList = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                               where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && country == c.PlantLocation
                               select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section, Value = c.Section }).Distinct().ToList(),


                Section = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                           where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && country == c.PlantLocation
                           select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section, Value = c.Section }).Distinct().ToList(),

                CarrierNameAppended = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                       where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.CarrierName) && c.CarrierName != null && country == c.PlantLocation
                                       select new SelectListItem { Text = c.CarrierName, Value = c.CarrierName }).Distinct().ToList(),

                StatusAppended = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                  where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.LoadCommodityStatus) && c.LoadCommodityStatus != null && country == c.PlantLocation
                                  select new SelectListItem { Text = c.LoadCommodityStatus, Value = c.LoadCommodityStatus }).Distinct().ToList(),

                PlantLocation = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                 where (c.PlantLocation == c.PlantLocation)
                                 select new SelectListItem { Text = c.PlantLocation, Value = c.PlantLocation }).Distinct().ToList(),

                LocationAppended = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && country == c.PlantLocation && string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.TrailerNumber)
                                    select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section + " " + c.Location + " " + c.LocationID, Value = c.Section + " " + c.Location + " " + c.LocationID }).Distinct().ToList(),

                //Duplicate Entry Row Exchange (Where Row is Visible and TrailerNumber is not null) get the model id to filter out.
                DuplicateAppended = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                     where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Location) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && country == c.PlantLocation && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.TrailerNumber) // && c.Section == city //&& c.LocationID == DupVisibleLocationID
                                     select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section + " " + c.Location + " " + c.LocationID, Value = c.Section + " " + c.Location + " " + c.LocationID }).Distinct().ToList(),
            };
            //Capture the Section were currently in. 
            model.SectionCity = city;

            return model;
        }
    }

           //Model:

         using System;
         using System.Collections.Generic;
         using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
         using System.Linq;
         using System.Web;
         using System.Web.Mvc;
         using ClassLibraryQualityBI.DAL;

    namespace YardDog.Model
   {

   public class YardDogModel
   {
    
    public List<LocationData> LocationDataMasters { get; set; }
    public List<LocationData> LocationDatas { get; set; }
    //public List<LocationData> Location { get; set; }
    public List<LocationData> TrailerNumber { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PlantLocation { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Location { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> LocationList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SectionList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SectionListAppended { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> LocationAppended { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Section { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> ListDuplicates { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> UserName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> TrailerNumberAppended { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> TrailerNumberListAppended { get; set; }
    
    public List<SelectListItem> CarrierNameAppended { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> StatusAppended { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> LocationListAppended { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DuplicateAppended { get; set; }

    

    //Allow the data to be transfered (Backend into SQL Server).
    [Required]
    public string Input_Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Input_Section { get; set; }

    public string Input_TrailerNumber { get; set; }

    public string Input_CarrierName { get; set; }
    public string Input_LoadCommodityStatus { get; set; }

    public string Input_DateLoaded { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Input_UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Input_PlantLocation { get; set; }

    //YardDogModel YardDogDatas = new YardDogModel();
    //string TrailerNumber = Input_TrailerNumber;

    public bool SelectedMoveIsChecked { get; set; } = false;
    public bool SelectedMoveToChecked { get; set; } = false;
    public string LocationAppendedLbl { get; set; }
    public string UserNameLbl { get; set; }
    public string UserPlantLocation { get; set; }
    public string LblUserPlantLocation { get; set; }
    public string LblPlantLocation { get; set; }
    public string LblUserName { get; set; }
    public string LblUserLocationNumber { get; set; }
    public int DupVisibleLocationID { get; set; }

    
    //Admin control:
    public string AdminFlag { get; set; }
    public string AdminLevel { get; set; }

    //Error Labels:
    public string ErrorFoundWebGridUser { get; set; }
    public bool AlreadyInTable { get; set; }
    //public string LocationAppended { get; internal set; }
    public int DuplicatesFoundInTable { get; set; } = 0;
    public string ErrorDuplicateFoundInTable { get; set; }

    public DateTime UserLoggedInTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime DupRowMovedTimeStamp { get; set; }


    }
   }

      //J-Query to capture values: 
       
       //=============== Header Link Selection (Keep Section) ===============/
    //When the header link is clicked, after refresh keep the list. 
      var selectedSection = $('#ddlSection').children("option:selected").val();
      $(document).on("click", "#webGrid th", function () {
   
     alert($(this).closest('th').text());
     alert("Section: " + selectedSection);
     $('content, .ddlSection').val(selectedSection);
     if ($(selectedSection != null)) {
   
     $('.ddlSection > option[value="' + selectedSection + '"]').prop('selected', true);
 
        $('#webGrid').dataTable({
            stateSave: true
        });
     }
  });

  //Capture the current ddlSection. 
    $("body").on("click", ".ddlSectionButtons", function () {
    var ddlSectionButtons = $(this).closest('#ddlSectionButtons').val();
    if ($('.ddlSectionButtons').val() != null) {
        alert("Section: " + ddlSectionButtons);
    };
 });

       [/Code]
```

Populate All List data:
[image]

Category List (when button is chosen, or drop-down chosen):
[image]

After you click on the header link "Section", it does not stay in the Section, instead it goes back to the All List population. Can we use J-Query to keep it in the Section Category that was previous??? I'm not sure how to go about this.

I got the buttons to reflect when a button is chosen, but when I do a function like the header link, the page goes back to default page and doesn't keep the current Section selection.
[image]

Comment: ` but when I go to sort the category, it displays all the data list from then on (everything) and the category list is gone to the everything list.`Which part of the code is your sort code?

Comment: It loses focus on the button after submitting is what I am seeing. The only sort code that I have is  WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model.LocationDatas, canPage: true, canSort: true, sortDirectionFieldName: "Location, Section", rowsPerPage: 50);
    webGrid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

Comment: During sort, the web grid needs to load the current section if it is not null and sort ASC or DESC after sort header link submits.

Comment: `It loses focus on the button after submitting is what I am seeing.`I think you need to pass the value of Section when you want to sort the category.